# Flowable not updated after inserting data inside a transaction

Tags: java, rx-java2, android-room

When we use a Flowable to get an update notification after inserting a new data-base row, works fine.
But when the insertion is done inside another explicit transaction, the Flowable does not get a notification.

To illustrate the issue, I've forked the `BasicRxJavaSample` from `android-architecture-components` and added 2 test-methods to [UserDaoTest.java](https://github.com/tmtron/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicRxJavaSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/observability/persistence/UserDaoTest.java#L70)

```
@Test
public void testFlowable() {
    // When subscribing to the emissions of the user
    final TestSubscriber<User> userTestSubscriber = mDatabase.userDao().getUser().test();

    userTestSubscriber.assertValueCount(0);

    // When inserting a new user in the data source
    mDatabase.userDao().insertUser(USER);

    userTestSubscriber.assertValueCount(1);
}
```

This works fine. But when I do the same inside of an explicit transaction it does not work:

```
@Test
public void testFlowableInTransaction() {
    // When subscribing to the emissions of the user
    final TestSubscriber<User> userTestSubscriber = mDatabase.userDao().getUser().test();

    userTestSubscriber.assertValueCount(0);

    // When inserting a new user in the data source
    mDatabase.beginTransaction();
    try {
        mDatabase.userDao().insertUser(USER);
        mDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();

    } finally {
        mDatabase.endTransaction();
    }

    userTestSubscriber.assertValueCount(1);
    // this fails - the userTestSubscriber is still empty!
}
```

Note: this example is of course simplified, just to illustrate the issue.

Here's the generated `DaoImpl.insertUser()`:

```
  public void insertUser(User user) {
    __db.beginTransaction();
    try {
      __insertionAdapterOfUser.insert(user);
      __db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
      __db.endTransaction();
    }
  }
```

We can see that this code uses a transaction and also my test-code uses another transaction.
According to the [SupportSQLiteDatabase-beginTransaction()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/db/SupportSQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction()) docs, nesting transactions should be okay.

Is this maybe a room-bug?

The room version of this project is `1.0.0-alpha3`, but I can also see this problem with version `1.0.0-alpha8` (in another project)

Comment: as a temporary hacky workaround I can call `mDatabase.getInvalidationTracker().refreshVersionsSync();` after the transaction block

Comment: Issue on the Google-issue tracker: [#65471397](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65471397)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in room: [#65471397](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65471397)

I verified that the bug has been fixed with version `1.0.0-rc1`